# Internal Error 500 - Only Web MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like some help in relation to internal error 500 All my application works perfectly on the local server . When I upload via ftp . Web application works by entering a PartialView . Error it gives is " Internal Error 500 " . Does the web server does not support the MVC5 FrameWork 4.5 ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: just check path of the partial views you have given in your mvc app...instead of hardcoded paths try helpers like `@Url.Action()` and `@Url.Content()` and `@Html.Action()`

Comment: I reviewed all the path and are standardized as you mentioned . The confusing is that the PartialView is displayed , but only the ajax this field of internal error 500

Answer (score 1):

The error

Internal Error 500

is a generic error message which indicates that the application is having serious problems. The message is generic so as to avoid giving away any sensitive information about the inner workings of your application. However, you can tell the application to provide a more detailed error message by ensuring that custom error pages are turned off: go to your web.config and make sure the `mode` attribute of the `customErrors` element is set of 'Off':

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then try refreshing the application in your browser - it will give you more information that you can use to track down the problem.